# Why my foreach loop break right after it reaches the iframe as HTML?

Tags: laravel, iframe, foreach

I save the iframe link into my database like this

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

and when i try to loop through my post in my blade file it breaks after the 1st record. If i just loop through using {{ }} i am fine but when i try to go with  {!! !!} it breaks after the 1st loop with no error

```
@foreach ($data as $sermon)
<div>
    <h1>{{ $sermon->title}}</h1>

    <p>{{ $sermon->body}}</p>

    <div><img src="{{ asset('img/sermons/' . $sermon->sermon_image)}}" alt=""> </div>
    <div>{!! $sermon->video !!}</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: If you remove `{!! $sermon->video !!}` it displays all records?

Comment: I would expect it the other way around, as `{!! !!}` doesn't encode the HTML. Is there something in the log file?

Comment: But what "breaks"? Locally in the HTML, or remotely in the PHP?

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a closing `</iframe>` tag

to fix ensure the value of `$sermon->video` has a closing `</iframe>` tag

Comment: Yeah, missing a closing tag for my iframe.